# How to interate by divided by 2 in for loop (Java)

Tags: java

I am having trouble figuring out how i would iterate by 0.5 in a for loop in Java. For example, `(i*0.5) {` is not possible. Any help is appreciated, sorry if question seems dumb

Comment: Can you show your full code for the *loop*?

Comment: What you mean by "`(i*0.5)` is not possible"? And you probably want `i+=0.5` if anything.

Comment: Don't forget that you can also divide by 2 by **dividing by 2** (;->)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    double i=1000;
    System.out.println("Result of While loop");
    while(i > 10) { //While loop
        System.out.println("Value "+i);
        i = i*0.5;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Result of For loop");
    for(double j=1000; j>10; j=j*0.5) {
        System.out.println("Value "+j);
    }       
}
```

**output**

```
Result of While loop
Value 1000.0
Value 500.0
Value 250.0
Value 125.0
Value 62.5
Value 31.25
Value 15.625

Result of For loop
Value 1000.0
Value 500.0
Value 250.0
Value 125.0
Value 62.5
Value 31.25
Value 15.625
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops iterate until a condition is met, and on each iteration the variable that is checked to see if the condition is met is modified. But that variable doesn't have to be an integer, and it doesn't have to be incremented by one on each step. See the following code:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      for (float f = 0.0f; f <= 2; f = f+0.5f) {
          System.out.println(f);
      }
    }
}
```

**Output**

0.0

0.5

1.0

1.5

2.0

So as you can see this iterates in increments of 0.5 as you want. And obviously you can do decrements as well.

Answer (score 0):

No dumb question! The syntax for this is:

```
for (var i = 10f; i > 2; i = i * 0.5f) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The „f“ tells the compiler that it’s a float, not a double. But you can of course use double, too.